# Use javascript parameter as razor array index

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use a parameter in my javascript function as the index parameter to my razor array.

```
function loadTemplate(index) {
    $("#wellContainer").empty();
    var htmldata = @Model.ServiceTemplateList[index].html
    $("#wellContainer").append(htmldata);
}
```

I get `The name index does not exist in the current context`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: from where you calling `loadTemplate()` function

Comment: From a regular onClick=loadTemplate(1) link. However i can't compile my code due to the error.

Comment: You can't do it that way. The code and statements in Razor are processed on your server before the page gets delivered to the browser and javascript even starts to work. Your razor statement does not know this index because it simply does not exist in that stage.

Comment: Is there anyway to access the model at runtime?